# Android 6.0: Why can't I assign negative values to byte and short variables?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

After narrowing down a weird bug in my code that suddenly happened for no reason (the same code was working well for 2 years), I found that when I try to assign a negative value to a `byte` or `short` field, it assigns a positive value like if the field was unsigned (for example, -1 becomes 255). It happens on emulators running Android 6.0 (x86 and ARM) but works well on older versions.

Here are some test cases that make absolutely no sense :

```
class Test {
    byte value = -1;
}

Test test = new Test();
Log.i("Test", "Value : " + test.value); // Output : "Value : 255"

test.value = (byte) -1;
Log.i("Test", "Value : " + test.value); // Output : "Value : 255"

test.value = (byte) -2;
Log.i("Test", "Value : " + test.value); // Output : "Value : 254"

test.value = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
Log.i("Test", "Value : " + test.value); // Output : "Value : -128"

byte b = -1;
Log.i("Test", "Value : " + b); // Output : "Value : -1"
```

The following one is particularly funny because Android Studio highlights the second line and tells me that `test.value == 255` is always false...

```
test.value = (byte) -1;
Log.i("Test", "Equals : " + (test.value == 255)); // Output : "Equals : true"
Log.i("Test", "Equals : " + (test.value == -1)); // Output : "Equals : false"
Log.i("Test", "negative? : " + (test.value < 0)); // Output : "negative? : false"
```

If I use a `short` instead of a `byte`, the same strange behavior happens (except that the first two cases output `Value: 65535` instead of 255). If I use an `int`, it works as expected. The bug seems to happen only when storing negative values in class fields.

Unfortunately, I can't try on a real device running Android 6.0 so I don't know if it's specific to the emulator or not.

Comment: from the docs The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)

Comment: @KaranMer That's right, this is why I say it makes no sense that a byte variable can store a value of 255 like in my examples.

Comment: You can try this on real devices running android 6.0 and if the bug still persists you should report a bug to google and let them have a look into this.

Comment: I ran your code here https://ideone.com/WwtNY7 and it works as expected. Can you try to update your jdk? and also create new emulator for android 6.0

Comment: This would be a serious bug. There is no way `byte value = -1;` could result in `255` with a spec compliant virtual machine. For example, `Log.i("Test", "negative? : " + (test.value < 0))`  should in your case print "false" which is not right. That's like `-1 == 255` is true.

Comment: It does the same thing to me on Emulator 6.0, but when I debug it, with breakPoint on the Log, it showed me correctly. Try it yourself! Indead I think is a bug..

Comment: @Rucsi Apparently if I set a breakpoint on the Log, it shows -1 because the value seems to really become -1 (it also shows -1 in the log), but if I don't set a breakpoint it shows 255.

Comment: @zapl I added a few more tests in my question that show that the value is really 255 and not -1. What is really weird is that I can store -128 in the same variable later (but only by using Byte.MIN_VALUE), so it is clearly not stored in a single byte in memory...